# Принцип формирования таблиц в DataSet.ReadXml

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Считал схему и Xml в DataSet

```
DataSet temp = new DataSet();
temp.ReadXmlSchema("schema.xsd");            
temp.ReadXml("xml_file.xml");
```

Соответственно получил набор взаимосвязанных таблиц с данными, но непонятно на каком основании происходит деление схемы на таблицы, может кто-нибудь подробнее объяснить этот механизм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь неплохо объяснено: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241320/c-how-does-dataset-readxml-filepath-work-with-my-xml-file-that-has-object

Пример данных:

```
  <items>
  <item>
      <itemProperty1>Propeterty1</itemProperty1>
      <itemProperty2>Propeterty2</itemProperty2>
      <propertyWithSubProperties1>
         <subprop1>subProp1</subProp1>
         <subprop2>subProp2</subProp2>
         <deeperPropertyWithSubProperties1>
              <deeperSubProperty1>data</deeperSubProperty1>
              <deeperSubProperty2>data2</deeperSubProperty2>
         </deeperPropertyWithSubProperties1>
      </propertyWithSubProperties1>
  </item>
  ...More items
  </items>
```

Разложение на таблицы:

В итоге `DataSet` содержит 3 таблицы:

- `dataSet.Tables[0]`:
  столбцы `itemProperty1`, `itemProperty2` и `item_Id`.
- `dataSet.Tables[1]`:
  столбцы `subProp1`, `subProp2`, `propertyWithSubProperties1_Id` и `item_Id`.
- `dataSet.Tables[2]`:
  столбцы `deeperSubProperty1`, `deepSubProperty2` и `propertyWithSubProperties1_Id` .

`Tables[0]` связывается с `Tables[1]` по автоматически создаваемому идентификатору в колонке `item_Id`.

`Tables[1]` линкуется с `Tables[2]`, используя автогенерируемую колонку `propertyWithSubProperties1_Id`.